# In Dax How to return a specific value from a column

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

In Dax(PowerBI) From a table named customerParent, from the column named Parent (data type Text) I am wanted to return a filtered value from it say "000000"
in other words like:
`if CustomerParent[Parent] = "000000" return CustomerParent[Parent]`

```
SELECT Parent
FROM CustomerParent
WHERE Parent = '000000';
```

I have tried several things in Dax and have had no success
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a measure like this

`parent = calculate(max(tbl[parent]),filter(values(tbl[parent]),tbl[parent]='000000'))`